# Chunk a variable into parts and sum the total in each part

Tags: python, pandas

My dataset has 2 million observations. I want to split it into 200 categories based on the value of a variable, 'rv'. For example, imagine I had the categories 0-1000, 1000-2000, 2000-3000, 3000-4000, 4000-5000 I would want to split an observation with value 4500 like this: 1000 in each of the 1st 4 categories, and 500 in the final category. I have the following code, which works but is very slow:

```
# create random data set
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = np.random.randint(0, 5000, size=2000)
df = pd.DataFrame({'rv': data})

#%% slice
sizes = [0, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000]
size_names = ['{:.0f} to {:.0f}'.format(lower, upper) for lower, upper in zip(sizes[0:-1], sizes[1:])]

for lower, upper, name in zip(sizes[0:-1], sizes[1:], size_names):
    df[name] = df['rv'].apply(lambda x: max(0, (min(x, upper) - lower)))

# summary table
df_slice = df[size_names].sum()
```

Are there better ways of doing this, where better means faster principally? With 2 million observations and 200 categories this takes quite a long time (not sure how long as I stopped the code before it had finished).

Comment: Are you able to sort your data before processing?

Comment: Yes, I can sort the data. Would that speed it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote an algorithm that sorts the data beforehand, which takes it from a O(n*m) loop (over the data and the categories) to a O(n) loop (just over the data, albeit there is a O(n log n) time for sorting it).  By sorting it, you already know which bin you're in and just have to take care of the summing for that particular bin, then apply the sum to that bin and all bins below it once per bin. It takes about 1.2 seconds on 2 million data points over 200 categories.  Hope it helps:

```
from time import time
from random import randint

data = [randint(0, 4999) for i in range(2000000)]
sizes = range(0, 5001, 25)
bound_pairs = [[sizes[i], sizes[i + 1]] for i in range(len(sizes) - 1)]
results = [0 for i in range(len(sizes) - 1)]

data.sort()

curr_bin = 0
curr_bin_count = 0
curr_bin_sum = 0
for d in data:
    if d >= bound_pairs[curr_bin][1]:
        results[curr_bin] += curr_bin_sum
        for i in range(curr_bin):
            results[i] += curr_bin_count * (bound_pairs[i][1] - bound_pairs[i][0])
        curr_bin_count = 0
        curr_bin_sum = 0

        while d >= bound_pairs[curr_bin][1]:
            curr_bin += 1

    curr_bin_count += 1
    curr_bin_sum += d - bound_pairs[curr_bin][0]

results[curr_bin] += curr_bin_sum
for i in range(curr_bin):
    results[i] += curr_bin_count * (bound_pairs[i][1] - bound_pairs[i][0])
```

EDIT: There may be some issues here depending on whether you want the upper bound or lower bound to be inclusive or exclusive. I leave the particulars to you.